# JavaScript included in base.html doesn't work in extending template

Tags: javascript, django

I have the following project file structure:

[image]

In base.html, I'm importing some JS that is meant to add an onclick event to the button in the html file:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/workoutcal.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

{% block userwidget %}
<button type="button" id="logoutbutton">Logout</button>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}{% endblock %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/base.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

base.js:

```
logoutbutton = document.getElementById("logoutbutton");
logoutbutton.onclick = logout;

function logout(){
    window.location = "/workoutcal/logout";
}
```

Then, in calendar.html:

```
{% extends "workout/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
```

The button shows up in the browser, but when I click it, nothing happens. From the browser console I get these errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/static/js/base.js net::ERR_ABORTED
localhost/:359 
GET http://localhost:8000/static/js/base.js 404 (Not Found)
```

So the static files are obviously not found. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

from settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

`STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILE_DIRS` are not set.

Comment: It has to be `window.location.href`. `window.location` is an object and you're replacing that object with a `String`.

Comment: That line works fine, the problem is that the js isn't found.

Comment: Please post the values for `STATIC_ROOT`, `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILE_DIRS` from your `settings.py`.

Comment: You got it, see my edit.

Comment: I'd put subdirectory `workout` in the `static` directory under `workout`, thus having the same patten like the `templates`: `workout -> static -> workout -> js -> base.js`. In the template then use `{% static 'workout/js/base.js' %}`. Do the same for `workoutcal` and its static files.